# Is there a better way to solve this problem in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Well I have the following problem: Let $\alpha = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $\beta=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ be two bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v_1=(1,0,1)$, $v_2=(1,1,0)$ and $v_3=(0,1,1)$. It's known that if we denote $[I]^\alpha_\beta$ the matrix of the identity map in the basis $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have:

$$[I]^\alpha_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Find $u_1,u_2,u_3$ in the cannonical basis. My approach was the following: let $\epsilon = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the cannonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $[I]^\beta_\epsilon$ be the change of basis matrix from $\beta$ to $\epsilon$ and $[I]^\alpha_\epsilon$ be the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\epsilon$, then we have the relation:

$$[I]^\alpha_\epsilon = [I]^\beta_\epsilon [I]^\alpha_\beta$$

And we want to find $[I]^\beta_\epsilon$, so we compute the inverse $([I]^\alpha_\beta)^{-1}$ and then $[I]^\beta_\epsilon = [I]^\alpha_\epsilon ([I]^\alpha_\beta)^{-1}$ and we can get the $u_i$ as the columns of this matrix.

Now, is there another better way to find these vectors?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I think that yours is the simplest way just one remark: $[I]_\epsilon^\beta$ is called the change of basis from $\epsilon$ to $\beta$ not the contrary.

Comment: @BryanUrízar Can you give me a reference I've seen lots of books and I have  found one way.

Comment: @BryanUrízar You gave me two examples that confirm my position. Please meditate.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in a comment:

> I think that yours is the simplest way just one remark: $[I]^β_ϵ$ is called the change of basis from $ϵ$ to $β$ not the contrary. –  Sami Ben Romdhane Aug 24 '13 at 20:25

Comment: This probably needs to be improved to be more explicit. It looks like the comment you're talking about has disappeared.

Comment: @rschwieb I disagree. The question was 'is there a better way of doing this?' The reply to this is 'I think yours is the simplest way'.

Comment: Dear @JessicaB : Oh. Well, I doubt anyone else is going to understand that. I guess I'll just transfer the remark into the answer then. It is next to incomprehensible as it stands

Comment: @rschwieb I guess we must use different versions of English then. I don't find two sentences blurred into one, only one of which is the main point, to be easier to understand.

Comment: Dear @JessicaB : I regret that somehow my comment touched a nerve for you. This was not my intention. I only mean that explicitly writing what you are referring to is preferable to creating a fragile link with no explanation. Regards.